# Connect to IPv6 mysql using java

Tags: java

I am using org.springframework.version -- >3.1.0.RELEASE and my datasource is like below

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close" scope="prototype">
<property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
<property name="username" value="test"/>
<property name="password" value="test123"/>
<property name="maxActive" value="100"/>
<property name="maxIdle" value="30"/>
<property name="maxWait" value="16000"/>
<property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="30000"/>
<property name="minEvictableIdleTimeMillis" value="60000"/>
<property name="testOnBorrow" value="true"/>
<property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1"/>
</bean>
```

Here is below code to create jdbctemplate...

```
BasicDataSource bds = (BasicDataSource) ctx.getBean("dataSource");
bds.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://address=(protocol=tcp)(host=xx.xx.xx.xx)(port=3306 )/" + db + "?autoreconnect=true);
JdbcTemplate jt = new JdbcTemplate(bds);
```

I searched and this the url suggested to connect to IPv6 address. I am able to connect thro DriverManager.getConnection but not thro this datasource....Am i missing anything here

```
Exception
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: address=(protocol=tcp)(host=xx.xx.xx.xx)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.jav a:1215)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java :1127)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java :1063)
at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(Stand ardSocketFactory.java:243)
```

I am using Centos-6.2 x86_64, I have checked the /etc/hosts and everything looks fine.

Comment: Please go though http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/ipv6-server-config.html .... it talks about configuring MySQL for ipv6

Comment: My my.cnf has the following to allow ipv6

[mysqld]
bind_address=::

And also skip-networking is not in my my.cnf

I have configured the mysql and I am able to connect to the my mysql from another system using the -h <ipv6 address>.

Comment: From the Java code snipped given above I am not able to connect to the mysql. It throws the expection.